# Use svg-pan-zoom in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: svg, ipython, jupyter

I'd like to embed an external .svg in a jupyter cell, then be able to pan and zoom.  Specifically, I'd like to use the great [svg-pan-zoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) library.  This seems possible, considering similar extensions, such as leaflet and mapbox.

Just trying the example from svg-pan-zoom, gives the following:

```html
%%HTML
<html>
<body>
<h1>Demo for svg-pan-zoom: SVG in HTML 'object' element</h1>
<object id="demo-tiger" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom/master/demo/tiger.svg" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:1px solid black; ">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
<script>
require.config({
  paths: {
      panzoom: '//cdn.rawgit.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom/master/dist/svg-pan-zoom'
  }
});
require(['panzoom'], function(panzoom) {
    console.log("Loaded :)"); 
    
    var s = document.getElementById('demo-tiger')
    s.onload = function(panzoom){
        console.log('loaded')
        
        panzoom.svgPanZoom('#demo-tiger', {
          zoomEnabled: true,
          controlIconsEnabled: true
        });
        }
    
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The cell renders the image, but never the pan-zoom functionality.  After many different approaches, it still does not recognize the `svgPanZoom` as a function.

I've also tried loading it in the `/nbextensions` directory.  This did not work, either.

I'm not experienced with JS or the DOM, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the problem maybe that you are running panzoom on the object tag. I 'think' you would need to use it on an svg element, which would mean accessing it via contentDocument something like s.contentDocument.getElementById('the svg id') would reference the document within the 'object'. May help to just isolate it on a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: The problem appears to be that svg-pan-zoom does not load in Jupyter cells - despite it being just an html page.  I'm probably going to have to find some Jupyter 'expert's to take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: @jbeach did you end up figuring that one out?

Answer (score 0):

window.onload will not work properly in Jupyter for obvious reasons.
See https://github.com/vlasenkoalexey/tfgraphviz/blob/master/tfgraphviz/jupyter_helper.py for working helper method.

Answer (score -1):

There is a working example of using pan-zoom in a notebook in this thread :

https://community.deepnote.com/c/forum/svg-pan-zoom?expand_comment_id=623583&login_token=eZ3YucZ66GXYMtfxagm6B53rdAX5JHAkYsoK#comment_623583

```html
%%html
  <body>
<script src="https://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/dist/svg-pan-zoom.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; border:1px solid black; ">
<svg id="demo-tiger" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit; " viewBox="0 0 900 900">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
</div>
 <button id="enable">enable</button>
    <button id="disable">disable</button>

    <script>
      // Don't use window.onLoad like this in production, because it can only listen to one function.
      window.onload = function() {
        // Expose to window namespase for testing purposes
        window.zoomTiger = svgPanZoom('#demo-tiger', {
          zoomEnabled: true,
          controlIconsEnabled: true,
          fit: true,
          center: true,
          // viewportSelector: document.getElementById('demo-tiger').querySelector('#g4') // this option will make library to misbehave. Viewport should have no transform attribute
        });

        document.getElementById('enable').addEventListener('click', function() {
          window.zoomTiger.enableControlIcons();
        })
        document.getElementById('disable').addEventListener('click', function() {
          window.zoomTiger.disableControlIcons();
        })
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```